# Removing a trailing period from improperly joined Teradata column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a Teradata table that I've inherited that was not formatted in a great manner.

```
ID
123456789.
234567890.
```

I've tried:

```
TRIM(new_card_srgt_id (FORMAT 'Z(17)9'))
```

but my version of Teradata gave a funny error:

```
Format string has combination of numeric, character, and GRAPHIC values.
```

Any suggestions welcomed.

UPDATE: The suggestion to use TRIM(trailing '.' from ID) results in a numeric overflow when I went to cast it. Any other way to fix it.

Comment: `ID` seems to be a VarChar, not a numeric column. Try `TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM ID)`

Comment: What's the exact datatype of `ID` and what the datatype you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load data from a decimal field into a character field without specifying the format, teradata does the type conversion.  It inherently adds '.' to the trailing value.

If the ID field is char and it already contains '.' and you want to extract it as decimal without the '.' then the syntax is as follows

```
SELECT cast(id as decimal(15,0)) form table;
```

If the ID field is decimal and you want to extract it as character without the '.' then the syntax is as follows

```
SELECT  TRIM(ID (FORMAT 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ9')) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with:

cast(TRIM(trailing '.' from ID) as decimal(18,0))